# RStudio - Linear Regression with Groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, regression

So I have 2 groups and an x and y variable. I am trying to run a linear regression to see if there is a significant relationship between the x and y variables within each group but I also want to look at the significance between groups. Then I would like to plot those results and provide a p-value, equation, and R^2 value on the graph. How would I go about accomplishing this?

I am able to plot the data on the same graph using this code:

```r
ggplot(data_NeuroPsych, aes(x = Flanker_Ratio, y = Neuropsych_Delta, color = Group)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", fill = NA)
```

Then using this open source code I was able to look at the results separately: https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/blob/master/R/stat_regline_equation.R#L7

The issue with the above is the data is not on the same plot and it does not look at the comparison between groups.

Comment: I assume you would need to fit the model separately using `lm` then construct the annotation to add which shows the interaction. could you give some sample data so we can try make it work for your data? Are you looking for an interaction term between groups or just a difference in level?

Comment: Can you include your code where you used `stat_regline_equation`?